# Earning from movie direction

Tags: halal-haram

Asalamualikum.. My father is having a plan for a horror movie and selling it to a director to make it is the money he is going to earn from it is haram please let me know ASAP jazakallah..

Answer (score 0):

Involvement in picture-taking or picture-making is a major sin and hence impermissible.

The money earned from that will be impermissible.

And Allah knows best.